# Rails Acts as Taggable On--Multiple Context Tag filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, acts-as-taggable-on, param

I am using acts-as-taggable-on to tag a Car model. I have three different tag contexts: Make, Color & Features. The first two Make & Color are predefined in an ENV variable and the last context is user generated(automatic windows, heated seats  etc.)

What I'd like to do is make it so that from my index page Cars can be filtered by multiple tags at a time. So for instance, I'd like a series of checkboxes at the top of the index page a separate set for each context where a user can check Hyundai & Red and the index of cars would populate with only red Hyundais. At the moment I have a route and some code in my Cars Controller that allows me to filter by one tag but I'd like to modify it to filter by whatever a user selects.

**routes.rb**

```
  get 'tags/:tags', to: 'cars#index', as: :tag
```

**controller**

```
def index
 if params[:keyword].present?
  @cars = Car.tagged_with(params[:keyword])
 else
  @cars = Car.all.order(:cached_weighted_score => :desc)
 end
end
```

Comment: Chat about your view? Can you update in your question?

Comment: my view is pretty complex but it's just basically an each loop on the instance variable @cars

Comment: Do you use select option to search your tag?

Comment: i want to use a series of checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@selected_tag` is tags that have been selected as parameter in index page.

**Controller**

```
def index
 if params[:keyword].present?
  @selected_tag = params[:keyword]
  @cars = Car.tagged_with(params[:keyword])
 else
  @cars = Car.all.order(:cached_weighted_score => :desc)
 end
end
```

**View**

It's only prototype view so you have to combine with your own code.

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "keywords[]", tag.name, @selected_tag.present? ? @selected_tag.include?(tag.name) : '' %>
      <%= tag.name %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope I can give a general overview with my description.
For more information to  [prepopulate data in checkbox](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)

Comment: So that works-ish it creates the checkbox in the view but it automatically has all of them checked it also doesn't have a way to submit a query of selected checkboxes.

Comment: So I figured it out I needed a submit button and then I removed the @selected tag variable will update my code. Thank you your answer put me on the right track

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you are right. You can add submit button there. Good luck.